# How do I get the estimate shipping zipcode in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am writing a custom shipping rates module, and I can’t seem to figure out how to get the estimate shipping zipcode… I know how to get the zipcode once the order has been created, but not for the estimate shipping portion of the checkout process

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whole information about the customer's cart is kept in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` model until placing an order. So you can get the Shipping Address model from the Quote. And from Shipping Address model you can get the zip code, which is called a 'post code' there. Thus, the only thing you initially need is to get Quote for the customer.

The Quote can be got in different ways:

- loaded from DB by its id or by any other attribute
- received from the Checkout session
- received from the Checkout Cart model

The most general way is to get Quote by loading it from DB - this can be done in all the Magento workflows and areas (API, frontend, backend, etc.).

But for your case the most straightforward way is to get Quote from Checkout Cart model, as you don't need to know Quote id for it - at frontend Magento loads Cart with appropriate customer data automatically.

```
/** @var $cart Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart */
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$zip = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
```

To get a little more understanding, why the Checkout Cart is used in this approach: the Checkout module manages the whole checkout process at frontend. It processes composing cart, viewing it, going through checkout steps and placing an order. Checkout module also stores the customer's quote model in its Cart model. While Quote stores whole information and can be used everywhere to manipulate customer's cart, the Cart model is just a temporary service model to aid Checkout module in fulfilling its duty, and it can be used at **frontend** for **current** customer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
//or
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
```